# Adding text to WPF Line

Tags: wpf, text, line, uielement

How do I add text to a Line UIElement? I would like to have the text placed in the middle of the line.

```
<Line Stroke="Black" X1="{Binding From.CanvasCenterX}" Y1="{Binding From.CanvasCenterY}" X2="{Binding To.CanvasCenterX}" Y2="{Binding To.CanvasCenterY}" StrokeThickness="2" />
```

Is this possible?

Comment: wrap a <TextBlock> in a <Grid> with it. Since it looks like you're putting it in the center of a canvas, you can just center the <TextBlock>

Comment: A `<Line/>` is just a line. It can't contain text. you need a more complex `DataTemplate` or something. Post some more XAML.

Comment: @HighCore This is the only existing XAML in my the UserControl

Comment: @MikaelKP then add a `Grid` to the UserControl and add the Textblock and the Line inside the Grid.

Answer (score 0):

The following XAML code adds text to a Line UIElement. In this example the text is presented by a `<TextBlock... />`. The text is centered at the Line, but this can easily be changed by the `TextAlignment` property.

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelationName}" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    <Line Stroke="Black" X1="{Binding From.CanvasCenterX}" Y1="{Binding From.CanvasCenterY}" X2="{Binding To.CanvasCenterX}" Y2="{Binding To.CanvasCenterY}" StrokeThickness="2" />
</Grid>
```

`VerticalAlignment` and `HorizontalAlignment` places the `<TextBlock../>` in the `<Grid../>`

Answer (score 0):

You need to set X2 coordinate value based on length of Text for alignment.

```
<Line Stroke="Black" 
    X1="{Binding From.CanvasCenterX}" Y1="{Binding From.CanvasCenterY}"
    X2="{Binding To.CanvasCenterX}" Y2="{Binding To.CanvasCenterY}" StrokeThickness="2" />

<TextBlock Text="Line Between the Text!" 
     VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>

<Line Stroke="Black" 
    X1="{Binding From.CanvasCenterX}" Y1="{Binding From.CanvasCenterY}" 
    X2="{Binding To.CanvasCenterX}" Y2="{Binding To.CanvasCenterY}" StrokeThickness="2" />
```