# Adding text in lines in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I want to add text to a line through `C#` code for `Windows-Phone 8` app. Is that even possible? I have some lines as follows in a loop-

```
Line[] l = new Line[300];
int cnt=0;
for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<24;j++)
    {
        l[cnt] = new Line();
        text1[cnt] = new TextBlock();                    

        l[cnt].X1 = centre_X[i];
        l[cnt].Y1 = centre_Y[i];
        l[cnt].X2 = centre_X[j];
        l[cnt].Y2 = centre_Y[j];
        ---
        ---
        Here I want to insert the text say "Hello"
        ---
        Canvas12.Children.Add(l[cnt]);
    }
}
```

So, is there some way to add some text by adding some `textbox` or otherwise in the center of the lines?

Comment: It's not quite clear what exactly you want to do. Where do you want to place this text?

Comment: @AlexIsayenko I want to place the text at the center of the line. I cannot use any other element like `Button` or `Rectangle` because the lines are connected with centers of the ellipses. Basically I want to add text to this line preferably at the center of the line. This is similar to this question but here they have done it in `XAML` and I want to do this through `C#` -
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27251787/adding-text-to-wpf-line

Answer (score 0):

You need to place your line and textblock in some container, for example grid. And then you will add the grid to your canvas. Try out this one

```
var grid = new Grid();

var text = new TextBlock { Text = "Hello" };
grid.Children.Add(l[cnt]);
grid.Children.Add(text);

Canvas12.Children.Add(grid);
```